# Google maps on fragment show only map on android 6+

Tags: android, google-maps

I need Google map in a `Fragment`, with setMyLocation and markers, but in android 6 I see just map, without my location button and markers. In Android 4,5 everything looks good.

```
XML:    
     <RelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.team.noty.carowner.fragment.Map">


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/tech_centre_spinner_map"
        android:entries="@array/Услуги"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/tech_centre_spinner_mark_map"
        android:entries="@array/Марки"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tech_centre_spinner_map"
        />

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tech_centre_spinner_map"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, 
     false);  

        mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        service = (Spinner)
    view.findViewById(R.id.tech_centre_spinner_map);
        mark = (Spinner) 
    view.findViewById(R.id.tech_centre_spinner_mark_map);

        mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display 
    immediately

        typeSpinner();
        speckSpinner();

        try {

    MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



            mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                    googleMap = mMap;

                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
     Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=  
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && 
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), 
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != 
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        return;
                    }
                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-49.1222, 34.2322);
                    googleMap.addMarker(new 
    MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker Title").snippet("Marker 
    Description"));

                    // For zooming automatically to the location of the 
    marker
                    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new 
    CameraPosition.Builder().target(sydney).zoom(12).build();


 googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosit       ion));


                }
            });


        return view;

    }
```

Comment: Have you granted access location permission to your app? It seems that your `onMapReady` is not reaching `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`. Take into account that in Android 6 your users can manually revoke permissions

Comment: I am use genimotion, where i can check it?

Comment: You can go to Settings->Apps->Your app->Permissions

Answer (score 0):

I find the ansver if anybody need:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
            googleMap = mMap;


            //*** Permission StrictMode
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            }

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }




                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);



            locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(55.751244, 37.618423))
                        .zoom(12)
                        .bearing(0)
                        .tilt(20)
                        .build();
                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);

                googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
            }else{
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(55.751244, 37.618423))
                        .zoom(13)
                        .bearing(0)
                        .tilt(20)
                        .build();
                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition);

                googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
            }


        }
    });


    } else {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                new String[] {
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                },
                MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);

    }
```